Wrong @if @for intendation with newest Prettier with angular17 and VS Code
Using latest prettier with the following prettierrc file:
{
   "arrowParens": "always",
   "bracketSameLine": true,
   "bracketSpacing": true,
   "semi": true,
   "experimentalTernaries": false,
   "singleQuote": false,
   "jsxSingleQuote": false,
   "quoteProps": "as-needed",
   "trailingComma": "all",
   "singleAttributePerLine": false,
   "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
   "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
   "proseWrap": "preserve",
   "insertPragma": false,
   "printWidth": 150,
   "requirePragma": false,
   "tabWidth": 3,
   "useTabs": false,
   "embeddedLanguageFormatting": "auto",
   "overrides": [
      {
         "files": "*.html",
         "options": {
            "parser": "angular"
         }
      },
      {
         "files": ".prettierrc",
         "options": {
            "parser": "json"
         }
      }
   ]
}

Added also for html file the angular parser and in the prettier playground everything is working but with my vscode not. Reinstalled also prettier.
Getting this in VS Code:
@if(variableTitles().length >= 1) {
<div>
   @if(variableTitles().length >= 1) {
   <p>sdfdf</p>
   }
</div>
}

Expacted this:
@if (variableTitles().length >= 1) {
  <div>
    @if (variableTitles().length >= 1) {
      <p>sdfdf</p>
    }
  </div>
}

What did i wrong, any ideas?

Does this answer your question? Indentation with Angular 17 new control flow in VS Code

Your .prettierrc file looks correct. Are you using Prettier v3.1 or newer?

Here's the issue in the Prettier repo: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/14991

Thx for the answer and the hint to indentation-with-angular-17-new-control-flow-in-vs-code
I added prettier in the project. Thought that the extension is using the newest prettier but that was not the case.
